# Radtabcontrol color change when selected in wpf using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I have a tab control with two tab items in it.It works perfectly in normal style .But when i applied some styles in XAML the tabs are not swtiching and i couldn't select an tab item too why its so??
Below is the style which i applied to tabcontrol

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border" Margin="0,0,2,0" Background="#828282" BorderBrush="#828282" BorderThickness="1"  >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" ContentSource="Header"  RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#CDCDCD" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#CDCDCD" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,0" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and here is the tabcontrol code

```
<Grid>
    <telerik:RadTabControl Margin="36,10,64,37">
        <telerik:RadTabItem x:Name="RadTabItem" Header="RadTab 1" Height="23" Width="59">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Label>RadTabItem1</Label>
            </Grid>
        </telerik:RadTabItem>
        <telerik:RadTabItem x:Name="RadTabItem2" Header="RadTab 2" Height="23" Width="59">
            <Grid Background="Transparent">
                <Label>RadTabItem2</Label>
            </Grid>
        </telerik:RadTabItem>
    </telerik:RadTabControl>
</Grid>
```

and if i changed

`<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadTabItemStyle}">` get 
[image]

Comment: are you using implicit style?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabItem}">
```

By

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadTabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadTabItemStyle}">
```

Comment: did you try StaticResource RadTabItemStyle or StaticResource telerik:RadTabItemStyle?

Comment: @dahsra yes but you cann't put StaticResource telerik:RadTabItemStyle. please try StaticResource RadTabItemStyle

Comment: its not allowing me to put as please try StaticResource RadTabItemStyle